# Pipe viewer (PV) not working?

Tags: linux, pipe, ffmpeg, fifo, pv

I'm trying to use Pipe Viewer on a video pipe that I'm both writing and reading from.

The below command works perfectly when I pass temp_video.h264 as an `-i` input to ffmpeg. However, when I attempt to pass temp_video.h264 to `pv`, and then pass its standard output to ffmpeg, ffmpeg never opens temp_video.h264 (maybe it never receives it?)

What's wrong with my command?

Here is my full command:

```
sudo rm temp_audio.v
sudo rm temp_video.h264
mkfifo temp_audio.v
mkfifo temp_video.h264
arecord -Dmic_sv -c2 -r48000 -fS32_LE -twav temp_audio.v & \
raspivid -w 640 -h 480 -fps 10 -v -b 1000000 -o temp_video.h264 -t 0 & \ # WRITING TO TEMP_VIDEO.H264
pv temp_video.h264 | \ #PIPE VIEWER ON TEMP_VIDEO.H264
~/special/ffmpeg/ffmpeg \
    -framerate 10 \
    -i - \  #READING FROM TEMP_VIDEO.H264
    -i temp_audio.v \
    -ab 24k \
    -c:v copy \
    -c:a aac \
    -report \
    -f flv rtmp://209.85.230.23/live2/KEY \
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ffmpeg` accepts `-` as a marker for _stdin_? The man page on Debian (wheezy) seems to suggest you need to use `pipe:0` to read from a piped _stdin_.

Comment: I'm surprised that this works reliably even when passing the video input file name to ffmpeg, because it would require ffmpeg to follow its two input files as they are being written, if I understand correctly.